# Given a "free" finite group $G$, is the set of all its quotient groups closed under finite subdirect products?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group.

Let $n$ be an integer such that $G$ has the following property:

"$n$-Free property": $G$ can be generated by $n$ elements, and for any two generating $n$-tuples $(g_1,\ldots,g_n)$, $(g_1',\ldots,g_n')$ there is an automorphism $\sigma$ of $G$ such that $\sigma(g_i) = g_i'$.

Under this assumption, if $A,B$ are two quotients of $G$, then is every subgroup of $A\times B$ which projects onto $A$ and $B$ which is also generated by $n$ elements also a quotient of $G$?

Essentially, the idea behind my question is: Is the "Free property" sufficient to say that $G$ is a free pro-$C$ group of rank $n$ (in the sense of Ribes-Zalesski's characterization of free profinite groups in their book "Profinite Groups"), where here $C$ is the class of all finite subdirect products of quotients of $G$.

Comment: @EricWofsey You're right of course. Apologies for the hasty formulation of the problem.

Comment: I think you need $n$ to be the minimal number of generators, otherwise, no nontrivial finite group has the free property.

Comment: @verret Thanks, that is indeed the case I'm interested in.

Comment: Do you really mean minimally generated by $n$ elements, or that $n$ is the minimum number of generators. For example, does the cyclic group of order $6$ have the free property? With your current definition, it does not, because it admits a minimal $2$-generating set, but not all $2$-generating sets are conjugate under the automorphism group.

Comment: @verret I think it should make more sense now. I would consider the cyclic group of order 6 to have the 1-free property, but not the 2-free property.

Comment: @DerekHolt I would think they're far more prevalent than that. Wouldn't any characteristic quotient of $F_n$ have the $n$-free property?

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't think $C_6\times C_6 = C_4\times C_9$ the latter is cyclic (coprime orders), whereas the former is not. Nonetheless, I think you're correct. The right thing to require is that $G$ be a characteristic quotient of $\widehat{F_2}$, because $\text{Aut}(\widehat{F_2})$ surjects onto the automorphism group of any characteristic quotient (by a closed subgroup).

Comment: @DerekHolt I suppose in general, if you fix a finite $G$, and you take the product of all maps in $\text{Surj}(F_n,G)$, then the image of the resulting product map should be $n$-free. One mildly interesting explicit example I came across recently are the Heisenberg groups $H_n$ modulo $n$, where $n$ is an odd integer. In this case, let $V := C_n\times C_n$, then $H_n$ has underlying set $V\times C_n$, with multiplication given by $(v,i)(w,j) = (v+w,i+j+\frac{1}{2}\det(v,w))$. This makes $H_n$ into a central extension of $V$ by $C_n$, and is the free group of rank 2 in the category of central..

Comment: @DerekHolt extensions of abelian groups which has exponent $n$.

Comment: @WillChen Yes, sorry, my example was nonsense. So $C_k^n$ is $n$-free for all $k$ and $n$. I am deleting my earlier comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I believe the answer is yes - here's a sketch:

Let $H$ be a subdirect product of $A$ and $B$, then by Goursat's lemma, there is a common quotient $C$ of $A,B$ such that $H$ can be written as the fiber product $H = A\times_C B$.

By assumption, $H$ is generated by $n$ elements, say $(h_1,\ldots,h_n)$, where $h_i = (a_i,b_i)$.

By assumption, there are surjections $f_A : G\rightarrow A$, and $f_B : G\rightarrow B$. Since $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ generate $A$, and $(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ generate $B$, by Gaschutz's lemma, we may lift $(a_i),(b_i)$ (through $f_A,f_B$) to generating tuples
$$(\tilde{a}_1,\ldots,\tilde{a}_n),\qquad\text{and}\qquad(\tilde{b}_1,\ldots,\tilde{b}_n)$$
of $G$. By the "free property", these two generating tuples are mapped to each other by some automorphism $\sigma\in\text{Aut}(G)$. Suppose $\sigma(\tilde{a}_i) = \tilde{b}_i$.

But then, consider the surjections $f_A : G\rightarrow A$ and $f_B\circ\sigma : G\rightarrow B$. Their product defines a map
$$(f_A\times (f_B\circ\sigma)) : G\rightarrow H = A\times_C B$$
By construction, the image of $(\tilde{a}_1,\ldots,\tilde{a}_n)$ is precisely $(h_1,\ldots,h_n)$, which generate $H$, which proves that $H$ is a quotient of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, no -- Take $A = B = G$ to be the trivial quotient of $G$ by $\{e\}$. Then $A \times B = G \times G$ is not a quotient of $G$ for most reasonable groups $G$.

Comment: Ah, sorry, good point. I forgot a condition. I hope you don't mind me editing my question accordingly.

Comment: The same answer is still a counterexample in many cases. For example, $A_5$ is $2$-generated, and so is $A_5\times A_5$, so just take $G=A=B=A_5$, and the subgroup $A_5\times A_5$ of itself.

Comment: @verret Thanks, you're right! Hopefully this will be my last edit.

Comment: @verret But $A_5$ is not $2$-free.

Comment: @DerekHolt My answer and these comments were posted before the question was updated to include the $n$-free condition.